# Require distributed transactions for server-to-server communication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, distributed-transactions

I want to know limitations or disadvantages of enabling 'Require distributed transactions for server-to-server communication' on SQL SERVER 2012 please?
My SQL database Server 2012 have a subscriber database for Transnational replication config and there are some other production databases as well.

Answer (score 0):

A disadvantage is that [this feature will be removed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-proc-trans-server-configuration-option) in the next version of Microsoft SQL Server.

There are posts on the web stating trouble with transactional replication when it is on. Still, I tested it on a test environment and all kept going nicely, so don't know what to say about it.

As for linked servers, it should be fine, yet I underline the following from the link posted above:

> This option is provided for compatibility with earlier versions of Microsoft SQL Server for applications that use remote stored procedures. Instead of issuing remote stored procedure calls, use distributed queries that reference linked servers, which are defined by using `sp_addlinkedserver`.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/24157